# Valores de un uuid se recuperan de forma incompleta

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Verán, estoy aprendiendo laravel y lo qué tengo pensado con mi código es poder generar un id aleatorio que incluye números y letras, algo parecido como una uuid...

El punto es qué, en la base de datos llega la información sin problema alguno, pero cuando hago mi petición por GET, no llega el id de dicho registro.

[image: Cómo se puede visualizar en la imagen, el id si se inserta sin problema alguno.]

[image: El id llega como si fuera un int, cuando realmente debe ser un string y muestra los primeros números del registro.]

```
$user = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash, true);
$article = new Article();
$uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();

$article->id = $uuid;
$article->id_user = $user->sub;
$article->title = $title;
$article->content = $content;

$article->save();

$data = array(
  'status' => 'success',
  'code' => '200',
  'message' => 'Article created successfully.',
  'article' => $article,
);
```

Comment: Hola! He estado pensando... para mi caso estaría bien agregar dos columnas id, una incrementable y qué la otra me almacena mi uuid?

Comment: en el modelo tienes que habilitarlo

Comment: Hola. No, estoy seguro que en mi tabla no tengo alguna columna auto incrementable, al parecer en el GET me trae ese id según como está en la tabla que mostré en la base de datos, pero cuando encuentra una letra lo corta y lo envia.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con exactitud? Perdona, soy nuevo en esto de las API REST.

Comment: Es increible... ¡Esa fue la solución! Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder está pregunta. Encontré está información más detallada en https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent
De nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Cada modelo en Laravel extiende de la clase Model, la misma tiene 2 propiedades relevantes para este caso las cuales son:

- `protected $keyType`  cuyo valor inicial es es un *int*, pero como tus valores actuales incluyen caracteres entonces deberás modificarlo a *string*
- `public $incrementing` cuyo valor es inicialmente un booleano (true) pero lo colocaremos a false ya que la pk no estará aumentando en 1 por cada registro nuevo

Las anteriores propiedades las declaramos en el modelo en uso que sería: *`Article`* para anular el comportamiento actual y que se identifiquen con los valores necesarios.

Recomiendo leas [esto](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys)